# How to constantly update livedata object from a service with viewmodel in MVVM?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, service, mutablelivedata

I am trying to constantly update the UI based on a long-running service output.
Basically, I want to display and append a list of users one by one after they get processed by the bound service.

**MainActivityViewModel**

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<User> user = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private MutableLiveData<MyService.MyBinder> mBinder = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder iBinder) {
            MyService.MyBinder binder = (MyService.MyBinder) iBinder;
            mBinder.postValue(binder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBinder.postValue(null);
        }
    };


    public ServiceConnection getServiceConnection(){
        return serviceConnection;
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser(){
        return user;
    }

    public LiveData<MyService.MyBinder> getBinder(){
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

**My Service**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder(); 
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void starFetchingUsers(User obj){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
 /**********************************************************/
```

*Here i will be sending POST method one by one for 100 times and will get 
a response as a user object which needs to be a liveData. So once this object 
is changed after next post method, i want it to get displayed or appended on UI.*

**How to bind this dynamic user object variable to the MutableLiveData user created in MainActivityViewModel class? so this get auto updated in UI.**

```
/**********************************************************/
            }
        });

        thread.start();

    }
    public class MyBinder extends Binder{

        MyService getService(){
            return MyService.this;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I am missing in both classes.